# Executing an EXE from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-6

I'd like to execute an exe from an ASP.NET MVC application. Yes I understand that inherent risks of doing this, but unfortunately I really need to do it.

The EXE is a GUI application, but the arguments I pass it force it to run "silently" where it generates some data into a zip file and then quits.

The code to execute the EXE is as follows -- it runs fine in VS2008 on my development box -- but when I test against the actual server (Server 2003 - IIS6), it fails:

```
        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = "C:\.....";
        psi.Arguments = "-silent -file outFile.zip";

        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo = psi;
        proc.Start();

        proc.WaitForExit();
        log.Debug("Process exited: " + proc.ExitCode);
```

The exit code is: -532459699, so something obviously went wrong.

I am running the application on the server over an authenticated HTTPS connection (basic authentication), so I thought I'd be able to get around the problem by setting `<identity impersonate="true" />` in the Web.config file under the `<system.web>` tag. But -- that hasn't worked.

Thanks -- all help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you just want to zip up some files/directories?

Comment: Yes, but I striped out a few arguments as they're not relevant to the question. The actual process of figuring out what to zip is complicated and requires a lot of back end DLLs and things that I dont want to pull into my web app. So, I was trying to use our stand-alone EXE that does all the hard work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the impersonation suggestions were interesting, but ultimately my problem was with my console app itself. It was trying to write some log files to the user's application data directory (even with the `-silent` option...), which I wasn't expecting.

Removing those pieces (thus making it adhere to the `-silent` command) made everything work perfectly

Answer (score 8):

Your web site runs under a restricted user account.
Your EXE will run under the same restricted account unless you use impersonation.

Edit: support from Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158

Comment: I was trying to do that with the impersonate tag -- but I'll try the "code" method mentioned in that KB and get back to you

Comment: Yes, After a lot of debugging I found out that the app I was running was trying to write a log file into the user's application data directory ....... FAIL! Needless to say I removed that and everything worked fine, didn't even have to use impersonation!

Comment: @debracey Well, actually you might want your app to keep logging, it's valuable information you are logging, right? In this case, you should find another good location for your log file so that it can be safely accessed in either scenario. Plus, any logging mechanism should be 100% safe, meaning that logging should NOT break your application in any case...

Comment: in this case the logs were not interesting and unnecessary. The app was also trying to write some config files, so I added a new flag to block that since the ASP.NET app does not need the app to rewrite any config files

Answer (score 1):

Better to find out what are the real needs of your exe and give the `NetworkService` appropriate rights (on file system, registry ...)

It needs some reverse engineering (use sysinternals [`processmonitor`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)) but still you have a high secure system.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Impersonate` functionality of the `WindowsIdentity` class in your code only for that operation.  You don't want to impersonate a user that has rights to execute arbitrary .exe for the entire application.  Make sure you (the caller being impersonated) have rights to run it on the production server.