# calling an exe from asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, timer

I have an application written in C#. Basically its an exe. This application scans for the network at 3 seconds interval and populates the database with the network information.

I want to run this application from asp.net mvc for few seconds and then stop it and again start and stop.

I need to start the exe at the click of a start button and need to stop it at the click of a stop button. The exe will be running continuously until I click on the stop button after it gets invoked.

Is it possible to call this exe from asp.net mvc framework?

If yes, how can it be done? I need some pointers. Please provide me.

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905180/executing-an-exe-from-asp-net

Comment: What do you mean start and stop ? If you run the exe as it is, does it run infinitely, checking for the network at an interval? You can use Process.Start from within your asp.net code, but i am not clear on the start stop part of your requirement.

Comment: I need to start the exe at the click of a start button and need to stop it at the click of a stop button. The exe will be running continuously until I click on the stop button after it gets invoked.

Comment: On click of start button, invoke the exe using Process.Start. You can create a new process object with appropriate start info, and then invoke start on the same. On click of your stop button, you can invoke Kill on the same process object to terminate it. I woudl advise reading up on process start and kill methods, and also the link given by MVCKarl above to learn about the pitfalls of using this.

Comment: [This question is an XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What are you actually trying to solve for?  Most likely I would recommend writing a windows service that monitors for command to start and stop an internal process (using WCF, Mutex or something else).  Having a web application start a process means that it is more difficult to stop the process if the app-pool resets, I would never recommend this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will need namespaces System.Diagnostics & System.Timers. Then follow below steps.

```
    static System.Timers.Timer tTimer;
    const Int32 iInterval = 30;
    static Boolean IsProcessRunning = false;
    static Int32 iProcessID = 0;

    static Int32 SetTimerInterval(Int32 minute)
    {
        if (minute <= 0)
            minute = 60;
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        DateTime next = now.AddMinutes((minute - (now.Minute % minute))).AddSeconds(now.Second * -1).AddMilliseconds(now.Millisecond * -1);

        TimeSpan interval = next - now;

        return (Int32)interval.TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        if (!IsProcessRunning)
        {   
            ProcessStartInfo objStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            objStartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe";

            Process objProcess = new Process();
            objProcess.StartInfo = objStartInfo;
            objProcess.Start();

            iProcessID = objProcess.Id;
            IsProcessRunning = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Process objProcess = Process.GetProcessById(iProcessID);
            objProcess.Kill();
            IsProcessRunning = false;
        }

        tTimer.Interval = SetTimerInterval(iInterval);
    }
```

Then on your start button click...

```
    tTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    tTimer.Interval = SetTimerInterval(iInterval);
    tTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
    tTimer.Start();
```

You can stop this anytime by...

```
    tTimer.Stop();
```

And you are ready to go...